# Check if String is in Arraylist

Tags: java, list, contains

How can I check if my `Input` `String` is in my `ArrayList`?

I did it like this. But it always shows `"not equal"`. Althoug I insert `1` for example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input:");

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");

        if (Input.equals(list)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "equals");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "not equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `list.contains(input);`

Comment: Is it possible to add the Input in to the arraylist if it is not already exists?

Comment: check if the `List` contains the `String` prior to insertion? But it sounds like a `Set` is preferable if you do not want duplicates. You can choose `HashSet` if order doesn't matter, `TreeSet` if you want to use natural ordering or specify a `Comparator` for your own, or `LinkedHashSet` for maintaining insertion order.

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions. Variable names like your `Input` should always be *camelCase*. So `input` please. *PascalCase*  is only used for class names.

Comment: Down-voted because of *no research*. Next time, please check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). It clearly explains that `equals` "*returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal*". And it also shows that there is a [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method with "*returns true if this list contains the specified element*".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check does `List<T>` contains `T item` you should use `yourList.contains(T item)` in your code, you are using `item.equals(object)` which is completely different. In short what `equals()` does is it checks do both objects are stored in the same memory address. Although for some default classes this method is overwritten and works a different way, `String` class is a good example of that.

Comment: To be more accurate, for a `List` `equals` is usually implemented by calling `equals` on all elements, comparing if both contain the same elements. So a `List.equals(Element)` doesn't make much sense. It's intended to be used as `List.equals(List)`.

Comment: @Zabuza I didn't knew that :)

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

You wrote

```
if (Input.equals(list)) { ... }
```

with `Input` being a `String` and `list` an `ArrayList`. But, the `String#equals` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))) method compares if two `String`s have the same characters (like `"hello".equals("hello")`), not if the argument list contains the element you called the method on. To quote from its documentation:

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is `true` if and only if the argument is **not `null`** and is a `String` object that represents the **same sequence of characters** as this object.

---

### Solution

What you actually want to use is `List#contains` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))):

> Returns `true` if this **list contains the specified element**. More formally, returns `true` if and only if this list contains at least one element `e` such that `Objects.equals(o, e)`.

So the code might look like:

```
if (list.contains(Input)) { ... }
```

---

### Naming convention

Please note naming conventions. Variable names should always be in *camelCase*, so `input` instead of `Input`. Same for method names.

Only class names are written in *PascalCase*. And constants (`static final`) are written in uppercase *SNAKE_CASE*.